# Image comparison with PIL is not working as expected

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

i am trying to do a image comparison with linux  x screen shot image vs actual on doing that

i follows the python script

http://aatiis.me/2010/08/12/fast-image-comparison-with-python.html

it works and delivers a output for a sample duck image(snap_from_x_duck[image] AND resized_from_duck[image])  which i used for testing but when i load my actual image (snap_from_x.png[image] AND resized_from_org.png[image] ) it gives an error..

```
  Comparing 1 images:
 *  1 /  1: /opt/ad_re.png /opt/op.png ...
 Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "imgcmp.py", line 246, in <module>
         sim = cmp.similarity()
     File "imgcmp.py", line 212, in similarity
         cmp = self.compare()
     File "imgcmp.py", line 180, in compare
         diff.append(cmp.levenshtein)
     File "imgcmp.py", line 127, in levenshtein
         stra_r = ''.join((chr(x>>16) for x in self.imga_int))
     File "imgcmp.py", line 50, in imga_int
         self._imga_int = tuple(self._img_int(self._imga))
     File "imgcmp.py", line 120, in _img_int
         yield pixel[0] | (pixel[1]<<8) | (pixel[2]<<16)
 TypeError: 'int' object is unsubscriptable
```

IT IS CONFUSING TOTALLY REQUIRE SOME ASSISTANCE ON THIS

Comment: It looks like `pixel` is an int. post more code i.e. what is `_img_int`. Or alternativelly you could run a debugger on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is (very) likely going on there is that the recipe is made to work only with RGB images -  and your image is a paletted version, with only 1 byte  per pixel (thus, the pixel for the image is a single byte, not a iterable with the RGB values).

The solution for this is to convert your images to RGB before calling your compare function - 
just do:

`img = img.convert("RGB")`

Comment: i will try u r solution and before trying this out of curiousity y did the same code  work for the duck image.